# ISA Server: How to troubleshoot DHCP problem?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp, troubleshooting, isa-server, dmz

I've added a DHCP Server to my ISA Server. The purpose of the DHCP server is to provide addresses to a DMZ (on its own interface) for misc computers that need internet access but don't need to be part of the domain (internal) network. I believe I've setup the DHCP server correctly and I've created the correct rules in the ISA server, However I can't get an address from the DMZ :/

I can ping computers on the DMZ just fine and if I manually assign the addresses they can access the internet without a problem.

What steps should I take to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention your version of ISA, but I assume you've gone through a procedure like [this one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc302605.aspx) to add the necessary rules.

Personally, I'd use a combination of a sniffer on a client computer (like, say, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) and the "Logging" tab in the "Monitoring" node on the ISA server to watch the wire and see what's going on.

I suspect that you'll find that some part of the DHCP traffic isn't being allowed.

Comment: Yep, reply's weren't making it through. Stupid error.